# split string by line txt file - wrong number of lines?

Tags: javascript

Any idea why the code below would output "Loaded 7 accounts" if there is only 4 lines of text in the file? Thanks

```
const fs = require('fs');

let data = fs.readFileSync('./AccountsToBeMade.txt', 'utf8');

if (data) {
    let accounts = data.toString().split('\n');

    console.log(`Loaded ${accounts.length.toLocaleString()} accounts`);
} 
else {
    console.log(`No accounts loaded`);
    process.exit();
}
```

Comment: Copy paste the content of the file and share with us?

Comment: Trying to edit....figured this out. Added .filter(Boolean); to end of split line and its fixed now :) thanks!